# transitive action on finite abelian subgroups

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Let G be a group and K a finite subgroup of G.
Let H be some subgroup of the normalizer of K in G, and assume the action of H on K by conjugation is transitive on elements of K of same order.
Does H also acts transitively on isomorphic abelian subgroups of K?

Comment: There are several typos here, I think. Also, why mention $G$? Why not just say that $K$ is a normal subgroup of $H$?

Comment: For $n\ge 2$ the group $Sp(2n,p)\ltimes F_p^{2n}$ acts transitively on elements of order $p$ in $F_p^{2n}$ but not transitively on 2-planes (i.e. copies of $F_p^2$) in $F_p^{2n}$.

Comment: This is similar to YCor's answer. Let $\mathbb F$ be the field of order $2^n$. Let $K=\mathbb F^+$ be the additive group of the field, $H=\mathbb F^{\times}$ be the multiplicative group of the field, and $G$ the semidirect product of these two. $H$ acts regularly on the nonzero elements of $K$, but does not act transitively on the $4$-element subgroups of $K$ when $n>3$ (since there are too many 4-element subgroups).

Comment: I corrected the typos.
Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: Geoff Robinson, you are right, it's a much better way to put it

Comment: I would go even further than Geoff and just say that $H$ acts on the finite group $K$ by automorphisms, or that $H \leq \operatorname{Aut}(K)$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a counterexample where $H$ can be taken as the full automorphism group of $K$. Necessarily, $K$ is nonabelian. Namely, let
$$ K = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix}
                 a & x \\
                 0 & 1
               \end{pmatrix} 
               \mid a, x \in \mathbb{F}_{16}, a^3 = 1
       \right\}.
$$
($K$ is a semidirect product of $C_3$ and $(\mathbb{F}_{16},+)$, and a subgroup of the $G$ in Keith Kearnes's answer in a comment.)
Then $\operatorname{Aut}(K)$ acts transitively on elements of the same order (even some small subgroups do). But $K$ has two essentially different sorts of subgroups of order $4$ and type $C_2\times C_2$: Namely, $5$ of these subgroups are normal in $K$, and the other $30$ are not normal.